# How can I give a lambda function access to all SQS queues?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a lambda function that will be constantly running, and some SQS queues that will be dynamically created. I need a way to allow the lambda to access all of the SQS queues so that these dynamically created queues can be used - how can I do this?

Currently I am using an Execution role that has an iam policy with a single queue ARN, but it seems I can't create multiple execution roles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

As mentioned in the comment below it may not be entirely safe to open up SQS queues to everything, so I will keep my initial solution below for interest but in general a better solution would be:

Create the lambda function with an iAM role attached that has access to all SQS queues. The policy for this would look something like

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
          "sqs:GetQueueUrl",
          "sqs:ChangeMessageVisibility",
          "sqs:ListDeadLetterSourceQueues",
          "sqs:SendMessageBatch",
          "sqs:PurgeQueue",
          "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
          "sqs:SendMessage",
          "sqs:GetQueueAttributes",
          "sqs:CreateQueue",
          "sqs:ListQueueTags",
          "sqs:ChangeMessageVisibilityBatch",
          "sqs:SetQueueAttributes"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
      },
   ]
}
```

---

---

I initially managed to get around the problem by creating my SQS queues with permissions attached. When creating SQS queues you can assign a policy to them where you can specify permissions and users, for example the following policy allows all permissions to all users:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "SQS:*",
      "Resource": "{{ queue_arn }}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: That seems a little dangerous to give everyone full access to your SQS queue. I would create an IAM role for your lambdas, and set the `Resource` to use a wildcard for all your queues: `arn:aws:sqs:us-west-2:1234567890:*` (replace region and account number as necessary). Then have your lambdas run under that role.

Comment: You're right that is a much safer method, I have edited my answer to use your suggestion, thanks